# Get ID in datatables when the corresponding button is clicked

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables and Jquery to build my application. I am fetching data into the table from my server. The table has 3 columns, each representing consignmentID, ConsignmentName and a button "Add". I want to retrieve the consigmentID of the corresponding Add button clicked.

```
var oTable = $('#viewAllConsignments').DataTable( {
                "aaSorting": [ ], // Prevent initial sorting
                "sAjaxSource": "getConsignment",
                "sAjaxDataProp": "",
                "sServerMethod" : "POST",
                "bProcessing": true,
                 "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "consignment.consignmentId"},
                        { "mData": "consignment.consignmentName" },
                        { "mData": "consignment.consignmentId",
                          "bSortable": false, 
                          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                                    return '<button type="button" id="btn-packets" class="btn btn-success btn-packets">Add</button>';
                            }
                        }
                ]


        });
```

Comment: for each row while constructing the data add data-consignmentId="database value" to your button and on button click do this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont ever use duplicated `id`'s - `id="btn-packets"` - you are fine with the `.btn-packets` class.

Why not store `consignment.consignmentId` (==`data`) as a data-attribute on the button itself?

```
...
mRender: function(data, type, full) {
   return '<button data-consignmentId="'+data+'" class="btn btn-success btn-packets">Add</button>';
}
...
```

onclick :

```
$('#viewAllConsignments').on('click', '.btn-packets', function() {
    alert($(this).data('consignmentid'));
})
```

---

Good old `attr()` can be used too :

```
return '<button consignmentId="'+data+'" class="btn btn-success btn-packets">Add</button>';
alert($(this).attr('consignmentId'));
```

---

Save the whole JSON for the row as `data` :

```
return "<button data-row='"+JSON.stringify(full)+"' class='btn btn-success btn-packets'>Add</button>";
```

Notice I have swapped the usage of `'` and `"`. `stringify` returns a string using `"`.

now `data('row')` holds the entire object you can access right away in the click handler. Even if data is inserted as string, it will return the valid JSON :

```
alert($(this).data('row').consignment.consignmentName);
```

It would be easier if we could assign the data without `stringify()`; `data()` is meant to be able to hold objects - but something like `$(result).data('row', full)` will not work since the rendered button not is part of the DOM at the time it is returned from `mRender`, it is just a plain string.

Comment: Hey, I tried doing this and I always get "undefined" in the alert box.

Comment: I inspected each button and they have data-consignmentId set to the corresponding consignment.consignmentId. But the alert box is still saying undefined. :-(

Comment: @vkm - oh yes,  jQuery lowercases the data-attr internally, try `alert($(this).data('consignmentid'))` have made this little example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yk9fady5/** that demonstrates the issue. A "valid" HTML5 data-attribute would be `data-consignment-id`, but that would be even more confusing. I think is rather annoying jQuery does that.  If you simply cant make it to work use `attr` instead,  `consignmentId="'+data+'"` and `alert($(this).attr('consignmentId'))` - I suggested data-attributes just to be HTML5 compliant, but who really cares :)

Comment: Damn! Could have never figured it out on my own. Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Hey David, just one more query for my knowledge. What if i want to pass in multiple data on button click like both ConsignmentName, ConsignmentId.

Comment: @vkm, see updated answer. You could assign more `data` or `attr` attributes, but also just the whole row. `full` holds the complete JSON for the row. The example in the updated answer should work with your nested data too.  I _believe_ each row / JSON entity in `aoColumns` of yours is `{ "consignment": { "consignmentId":  "42", "consignmentName": "hello",..},..} `etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:`Add DATA Attribute to the ADD button.`

for each row while constructing the data add `data-consignmentId="database value"` to your button and on button click do this:`$(this).data(consignmentId);//required id`

Comment: Hey, I tried doing this and I always get "undefined" in the alert box.